# 10 objects are purely randomly assigned to 10 places - Number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

Quick and dirty:
10 objects are purely randomly assigned to 10 places. What is the number of possible arrangements?
The answer: $19\choose{10}$

But this seems counterintuitive. Might someone shed some light? My initial guess was $10^{10}$, however, this wouldn't capture cases like | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether the objects are identical.

**If identical:**

This would be like arranging 9 separation bars(|) and 10 identical objects(o).

For the case you stated above, it would be oooooooooo|||||||||.

The number of arrangements would then be $\frac{19!}{10!9!}$ =  C(19,10)

**If NOT identical:**

Your guess would be correct.

Comment: Could you motivate C(19,10)? Why 19 for example?

Comment: I edited my reply above.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the number of possibilities to divide 10 red balls over 10 boxes, we use a different approach. Count the possiblities using 10 red balls and 9 blue balls.
That is C(19,10).

The analogy between the boxes and the blue balls is that box 1 contains all red balls left of the first blue ball. Box 2 the red balls between the first and second blue ball, etc.

**However!** If your red balls are not identical, but $r_1 .. r_{10}$, you still will not have $10^{10}$, because you can't place one object on more than one location. But you'd have

$$ \frac{19 !}{9!} $$

Because the blue balls will still be identical.